# How to merge collection.concurrent.Map

Tags: scala, collections

What is the best way to merge two concurrent maps.

Here is my current impl :

```
private def merge[A, B](map1: concurrent.Map[A, B], map2: concurrent.Map[A, B]) : concurrent.Map[A, B] = {
  val mergedMap = map1 ++ map2
  val concurrentMap = new TrieMap[A, B]()
  mergedMap.foreach {case (k, v) => concurrentMap.put(k, v)}
  concurrentMap
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to take care of race conditions in the access of the map. In your code, when you merge the two maps and they are concurrently modified, you might miss elements or even "fall off the edge".

I'd propose the following (but needs stricter typing to `TrieMap`):

```
private def merge[A, B](map1: TrieMap[A, B], map2: TrieMap[A, B]) : TrieMap[A, B] = {
  val res = map1.snapshot()
  res ++= map2.snapshot()
  res
}
```

(didn't test this, but I hope the idea is clear).

If you don't care about concurrent access in this method, you could also just simple use a builder:

```
private def merge[A, B](map1: concurrent.Map[A, B], map2: concurrent.Map[A, B]) : concurrent.Map[A, B] = {
  val builder = TrieMap.newBuilder[A, B]
  map1.foreach(builder += _)
  map2.foreach(builder += _)
  builder.result()
}
```

This will avoid creating any intermediate structures.